# Is there a link between Group Theory and the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, modular-function

My question is twofold:

Does anyone know if there's a connection between the Monster Group and the Riemann Zeta function?

If there is a known connection, then I would be curious to know when and if the number 163 arises in the function, or in other Zeta or Eta functions.

Disclaimer: I am a ley mathematics enthusiast, not a mathematician.  I can promise no degree of rigor in this post.

Background: 163 is my favorite number, and I have a question about it.  It's the largest Heegner number. The Heegner primes, and especially 163, are really interesting because of their connection to the J Invariant. The J invariant, is in turn connected via "monstrous moonshine" to the "classification of the finite simple groups", which is widely considered to be the largest mathematical project ever conducted. Group theory is the study of symmetry. A $1 million Clay Mathematics Institute prize will be awarded to the first person to prove the existence of a property of the Riemann Zeta function which is related to at least one of its symmetries.  Often touted as the "holy grail of mathematics," the Riemann Hypothesis asks for a proof of the unchanging uniformity of the Real part of the function's non-trivial zeros: do they always remain at +1/2, regardless of how enormous the absolute value of the imaginary part might be?  We already know that the critical line is an axis of symmetry (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Other_results).

As far as I know there is no rigorous connection between the Monster Group and the Riemann Zeta function, but I believe such a connection exists. The number 163 and the other Heegner numbers seem likely to play some role in any proof of such a connection. Such a proof would not prove the Riemann Hypothesis, but any new links that can be drawn between the hypothesis and other areas of mathematics may prove useful in the eventual construction of a rigorous proof.

Comment: "The impact on our economy would be tangible, if it were solved today." Hmm, what do you think the impact would be? To whatever extent we rely on RH, it wouldn't seem to matter in practice if we can prove it, since we have strong empirical evidence that it is true. Of course, a proof could produce insights that affect our economy indirectly, but that's true of any mathematical advance.

Comment: @emery 'The Riemann Hypothesis has widespread implications for both cryptography and quantum physics. The impact on our economy would be tangible ...' Uh, very doubtful there'd be any practical impact.

Comment: Yeah, the biggest real world impact of proving Riemann hypothesis is that if you prove it, it will get you tenure anywhere you want.

Comment: What makes you think that such connection exists ? As for the applications in the real world, I agree with the other comments. As far as I know the RH would not have any impact on quantum physics (there is the Hilbert–Pólya conjecture but it's stronger than the RH). Note that we are pretty sure that the RH is true but we don't have a formal proof yet so people in the real world won't hesitate to consider it true.

Comment: I also agree that the proof of the Riemann hypothesis would have no consequences for our "real life" , neither does it have anything to do with quantum mechanics and we do not need it for cryptographical purposes (for this we only need that factoring is hard). Of course , a proof of the Riemann hypothesis would have many consequences in pure math and be a sensational milestone comparable to Wiles' proof of Fermat's last theorem.

Comment: I am not an expert for the monster group , but I doubt there is a connection to the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: I obviously made too many conjectures that were outside the scope of pure mathematics and my question was closed as a result.  The question itself, however, is purely about mathematics.  My statements about the links to cryptography and quantum mechanics were based on my reading of "The Music of the Primes" by Marcus du Sautoy.

Comment: I have removed "The Riemann Hypothesis has widespread implications for both cryptography and quantum physics. The impact on our economy would be tangible, if it were solved today." as it is not relevant to the question.  However the question is entirely about understanding mathematical concepts and so I believe it should be re-opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The so-called *class number problem* for the ideal class group includes the classification of the imaginary quadratic number fields with class number $1$. The "last" one in this list is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$ for the prime $p=163$. Dirichlet's class number formula connects the class numbers $h(D)$, where $D$ is the discriminant, with $L$-functions $L(s,\chi)$, a generalization of $\zeta(s)$. Deuring proved, that if the classical Riemann hypothesis is false, then the class number $h(D)$ satisfies $h(D) > 2$ for $-D$ sufficiently large. Heibronn proved that if the generalized Riemann hypothesis is false then $h(D)\to \infty$ if $D\to -\infty$.

This is not yet a direct link why $p=163$ arises in RH, but it is true that Gauss listed the following related problems in his book *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* together:

1. The class number satisfies $h(D)\to \infty$ if $D\to -\infty$.
2. There are exactly $9$ imaginary quadratic fields with class number one, namely $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$ with
   $$
   d= 1,2,3,7,11,19,43,67,163
   $$
3. There are infinitely many real quadratic fields with class number one.

Comment: So it sounds like the number 163 arising in RH and in the Monster Group does indeed wag a finger in the direction of some possible connection.  It's too bad that the number 163 is so small and one of the first few primes, as you can't really read too much into a number like that appearing in potentially unrelated areas of mathematics.  Thank you for your insight, this is a great answer!!